# How to remove subtotal from a excel pivot-table with mutiple data fields useing vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, subtotal

I can't remove all subtotals from a pivot table if it has more than one data field.

Nomatter how many row or columns labels it has, it wotks as long it has only one data field. Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub pivot_table()

    Dim wkb         As Workbook
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim sht2        As Worksheet
    Dim pvtcch      As PivotCache
    Dim pvttbl      As PivotTable
    Dim pvtrange    As Range
    Dim pvtfield    As PivotField
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set wrb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht = wkb.Sheets(Plan1)

    Set sht2 = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=sht)
    sht2.Name = "PVTBL"
    With sht
        Set pvtrange = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, pvtrange, , xlYes).Name = "sourcepvt"
    End With

    Set pvtcch = wrb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
 SourceData:="sourcepvt")

    Set pvttbl = sht2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtcch, _
 TableDestination:=sht2.Range("A3"), TableName:="Report")

    With pivottbl
        'code to set the row and columns labels and datafields
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
        .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each campos In .PivotFields
            campos.Subtotals(1) = False
            .ColumnGrand = False
            .RowGrand = False
        Next campos
    End With
    Set wrb = Nothing
    Set sht = Nothing
    Set sht2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

As I try to use the code I receive a error dialog box runtime error 1004:
Can not Set Subtotal Property of Pivotfield Class

Comment: My approach would be to record a macro and see what it looks like

Comment: Also, no need to set your 3 variables to `Nothing` at the end. This is redundant and will be done at `End Sub`

Comment: @urdearboy The recorded macro is the same for one or more `xlDataField`. End this is the only between a successful code (one `xlDataField`) to a runtime error 1004 (two or more `xlDataField`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is described within [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.subtotals) explanation of `PivotField.Subtotals`.

If you want to switch *all* subtotals types off, you can either set the `Automatic` subtotals to `True` (switches all other types off) and to `False` again, or you set all 12 types to `False` with the given array notation.

Subtotals can only be defined for non-data fields. So you must not loop over all `PivotFields`, but `RowFields` (or `ColumnFields`) instead. By this you can omit the `On Error Resume Next` also.

As `ColumnGrand` and `RowGrand` are defined once per pivottable, I placed it before the loop.

```
With pvttbl
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    ' defined once per pivottable:
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .RowGrand = False
    ' use RowFields only:
    For Each campos In .RowFields
        ' either this:
        campos.Subtotals(1) = True   ' Automatic on (= all other off)
        campos.Subtotals(1) = False  ' Automatic also off

        ' or that (all 12 off):
        'campos.Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    Next campos
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to loop through each `PivotField` and update each `.Subtotals` property. There are 12 of them. Since you don't want any subtotals, set them all to `False`. You'll need to ignore errors so that the loop won't stop.

```
For Each pvtfield In pivottbl.PivotFields
    'Disable subtotals for all fields
    On Error Resume Next
    pvtfield.Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, _
        False, False, False, False, False, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next pvtfield
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.